# Store array as variable then convert back to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, store

I'm making a javascript game but (not browser-based) but the engine I'm using has a bug that it deletes stored arrays when you exit the game. So to get passed that I want to store my arrays as variables and then when you load up the game convert them back to the arrays.

At the moment my game has only 1 array.
Someone suggested this code but it doesn't work properly in that when I run a script to print each element of the array on a different line it prints the first element on the first line but then on the second line it prints the rest like this: element1,element2,element3
Here is the code the person suggested:

> This code runs every time the arrays are updated. 
>   Here, the array is "questsActive", and the var it is stored in is "questsActiveVar".
>
> ```
>   questsActiveVar = questsActive.toString();
>   questsActiveVar = questsActiveVar.replace(",", "\",\"");
>   questsActiveVar = "questsActive=new Array(\"".concat(questsActiveVar,"\")");
> ```
>
> This runs whenever the game loads; it recreates the array that was
>   deleted
>
> ```
>   eval(questsActiveVar);
> ```

Comment: As @Genius observe in is response it could be a good thing to use JSON in your context, if you have a fair amount of data to save. http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only replacing the **first** item with the replace call.

Try this:

```
questsActiveVar = questsActiveVar.replace(/,/g, "\",\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an array from a `string` in javascript you need to use the function `.split()`. Here is an example:

```
var someStr = 'item1, item2, item3';
var array   =  someStr.split(',');   // place any character in here to split on
alert(array[0]);                     // => item1
```

From what I understand in your context I would simply save the `questsActiveVar` variable, then `.split()` it when the game loads again.

Comment: You can use `join()` to do the reverse; turn the array into a string: `array.join(',')`.

Comment: I can't use split because it converts the array contents into a series of strings and my array contains a series of variables.

Comment: @gabriel101x I'm not sure to follow. How can an array have variable and not their value? Could you add a simple example of that in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the issue, but why you want to store a part of javascript if you need to store only data? I'd suggest that you store in your storage a JSON-string of the array, and then parse it as an array when load.

The code should look like this:

```
var questsActiveVar = JSON.stringify(questsActive);
// questsActiveVar can be stored anywhere as a string
```

And to load it:

```
var questsActive = JSON.parse(questsActiveVar);
```

In this case you can store even more complicated variables with commas, sub-arrays, etc.